# How to get comments from gitlab?

Tags: api, gitlab

Is it possible to get comments from issues on Gitlab? as I read official docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html comments are not included there.

Comment: You should be able to get it via the discussions endpoint https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/discussions.html#issues

Comment: I get it https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the comments posted at an issue we will use the Gitlab API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/discussions.html#list-project-issue-discussion-items

```
GET /projects/:id/issues/:issue_iid/discussions
```

By providing the project **:id** and the **:issue_iid** , the issue_iid in this case would be 2
[image]

By providing the following one liner we can get the comments and their metadata for a specific project and issue

```
curl -s  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project id>/issues/<issue_iid>/discussions | jq '.[].notes[0]'
```

Comment: This however returns all discussion items, not only "real" comments but also automatically generated stuff by GitLab (e.g. when editing the description, GitLab adds a discussion entry such as "USER changed the description").